# Trying to compute a derivative

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $$\varphi(x):=\int_{a}^{x}2(y-x)f(y)dy+c_1x+c_2$$.

Prove that

$$ \frac{1}{2}\varphi''(x)=-f(x) $$

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem so far? What have you tried?

Comment: Firstly I thought about the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, but then I convinced myself that this not the case to applicate it. Then I tried with the difference quotient

Comment: Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (or the more general Leibniz integral rule) *is* the way to go. Here's a hint: $$\int_a^x2(y-x)f(y)\,dy=2\int_a^xyf(y)\,dy-2x\int_a^xf(y)\,dy.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\varphi(x)=2\int_a^xyf(y)dy-2x\int_a^x f(y)dy+c_1x+c_2$$

So

$$\varphi'(x)=2xf(x)-2\int_a^xf(y)dy-2xf(x)+c_1=-2\int_a^xf(y)dy+c_1$$

and

$$\varphi''(x)=-2f(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:: Try [Leibniz integral rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign).

Answer (score 1):

Hints:
1) you can derive each term in the sum separately.

2) you can rewrite the integral as two integrals

3) apply Leibnitz rule for one of them

4) the other one is a simple application of FTC.